# A girl is adopted by a heroic duke, but is sacrificed to save the world. She comes back to life and this time picks the villainess duke to adopt her

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

I can't remember the name of this Korean Web-novel I once read:

A girl is adopted in her first life by a heroic duke. She worked really hard and had respect for him, but another girl from Korea is reincarnated into her world and the church that used to support the main character is now supporting this new girl. And then she is sacrificed at the church to “save the world”. She comes back to the time she gets to pick which of the three dukes she could get adopted by and this time, to save her life, she picks the villainess duke.

She builds her power and becomes close with the duke and his two sons, but finds out that she has the power to summon devils and use their powers after completing a task for them. And through these devils, she finds out that the church worships an evil god that is trying to kill her.

She also finds out that she is the duke's lost daughter and that the church killed her mother and the reason for that is because, in a past life, she was the younger sister of the now evil god. The pope of the church is in love with that younger sister, as he somehow lived that long? So both the pope and evil god are after her for different reasons.

She ends up contracting strong devils and, through the original god's help, she’s able to defeat them both and lives happily with her family.

The main character has light brown curly hair.
(I might be wrong about some details; it's been a minute.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you actually mean the _villainess_ duke, or the _villainous_ duke?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245074/korean-manga-manhua-about-noble-daughter-being-sacrificed

Comment: @Valorum Having read the manhwa version of that, it is not "The Monster Duchess and Contract Princess".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[The Baby Raising a Devil](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/327tiqv/the-baby-raises-a-villain-pre-serialization)***...?

> Lablaine had already lived her life three times, and was now living it again. Due to a misinterpretation of an oracle, she had been raised as a "Child of Fate" and was asked to choose a guardian. During the first time she lived her life, she lived in a strict knight's household, but when the real "Child of Fate" appeared, she was sacrificed as a scapegoat for them. During the second time, she was abused by an outwardly respectable scholar; the third time, she ran away and lived as a beggar. Since the country seems to not be safe for her, she decided to leave it this time. To that end she chose… a family of the biggest and coldest villains in the kingdom. She just tried to get along with them for the time being, but her family has turned out to be absurdly overprotective and doting?!
>
> [image: Promotional image of "The Baby Raising a Devil."]

The protagonist wakes up as her younger self, having already lived her life three times over.

Due to a mistranslation by the oracle, she was falsely labelled as a child of destiny, and in her first life, ended up being sacrificed as a scapegoat by the knight she was raised by, after the true child of destiny appeared.

In her second life, she was raised by an outwardly reputable scholar, who subjected her to physical abuse by way of [beltings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belting_(beating)).

In her third life, she ran away and lived as a beggar.

Now in her fourth life, she's asked to choose between three adoptive fathers, and having already experienced unsatisfactory lives with two of them, she picks the third option this time, "the wealthiest man of the empire and a future villainous mastermind," the wicked Duke Dubblede, who has three sons.

You can read the web novel at [Novel Updates](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-baby-raising-a-devil/).

Comment: IT IS THANK YOU SO MUCH :)